# Проблема подключения com.vk.api:sdk в android studio

Tags: android, vkontakte-api

Для добавления VK Java SDK, в gradle(:app) прописал:

```
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        exclude 'META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties'

    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.vk.api:sdk:1.0.6'
    }
```

Пробовал обновлять gradle, гуглил, ставил более раннюю версию api, добавлял следующие строчки

```
        implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-slf4j-impl', version: '2.11.2'
        implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.11.2'
        implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.11.2'
```

Но всё равно выскакивает ошибка:

```
MethodHandle.invoke and MethodHandle.invokeExact are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)
Stack trace:
com.android.tools.r8.errors.a: MethodHandle.invoke and MethodHandle.invokeExact are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)
```

[image: скрин]

Android api 26 не имеется. VK Android SDK не использую, потому что уже написал проект на Java SDK в inteliJ.
Можно ли как-то решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что vk api написан с использованием Java 8, а Android работает на Java 7 из-за чего некоторые методы не работали. Писать свою реализацию я не стал, а решил воспользоваться этой библиотекой: https://github.com/yvasyliev/java-vk-bots-long-poll-api
Она довольно проста и похожа на оригинальную, поэтому переписывать пришлось не много.

Для запуска на андроид потребовалось только подключить библиотеку и добавить в Gradle пару строчек

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
    targetCompatibility 1.8
}
```

Удачи!